# How to add a dictionary to .json list written in file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to add a .json dictionary to the `"Steps"` list that's written in another file.

```
{
    "UPDATED AFTER IMPORT": {
        "ID"   : "UPDATED AFTER IMPORT",
        "Name" : "Sample Name",
        "Steps": []
    }
}
```

I am getting this error.

```
f["UPDATE AFTER  IMPORT"].append({"Steps":[outputfile]})
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

Here's what I tried.

```
with open (stepjson, 'r+', encoding = 'utf-8') as jsonfile: #open step template
    data = json.load(jsonfile)
data["Config"]["Script"].update({"Args":args_str}) #update args in step.json template
with open(json_dir+csvfilename +'.json', 'a') as f: #add edited step.json template to final .json file
    outputfile = json.dumps(data,indent=4)  
    f["UPDATE AFTER  IMPORT"].append({"Steps":[outputfile]})
```

Comment: Have you tried `f["UPDATE AFTER  IMPORT"]["Steps"].append(outputfile)` ? If your list already exists

Comment: Please provide the whole error message

Comment: @arnino Yes I have tried that, I got the same error message. I have edited and added the whole error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: '\_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977477/typeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs no it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use your file reference as a dict, this cannot work.
Something along these lines might be closer to what you are looking for:

```py
with open (stepjson, 'r+', encoding = 'utf-8') as jsonfile: #open step template
    data = json.load(jsonfile)
data["Config"]["Script"].update({"Args":args_str})

with open(json_dir+csvfilename +'.json', 'w+') as f:
    data_out = json.load(f)  
    data_out["UPDATE AFTER  IMPORT"]["Steps"].append(data)
    json.dump(data_out, f)
```

Edit: I changed the opening mode for the output, `w+` is probably what you want to use: you get the whole dict, modify it and write it completely back